# C++ Container of polymorphic objects with shared vptr

Tags: c++, containers, vtable, polymorphism

Suppose that I need to store a collection of objects of the **same type**, but this type can't be defined at compile time. Suppose also that once this type is defined, it never changes. As well known, when the type is not know at compile time, it's possible to store these objects using a container of pointers to their base class, i.e.,

```
std::vector<Base*> collection;
collection.push_back( new Derived() );
```

In this way, allocated objects will not be necessarily stored side by side in memory, because in each allocation the `new()` will return an arbitrary position in memory. Furthermore, there is an extra pointer (`vptr`) embedded to each object, because the `Base` class of course needs to be polymorphic.

For this particular case (type is defined once + type never changes), the above solution is not the optimal solution, because, theoretically,

1. it's not necessary to store the same `vptr` (sizeof() = pointer size) for each object: all of them points to the same `vtable`;
2. it's possible to use contiguous storage locations, since the size of the objects are defined at the beginning of the program and will never change.

**Q:** Do you guys know a strategy/container/memory allocator/idiom/trick/anything else to overcome those problems?

I think I could do something like this (using the classic *Shape* example):

```
struct Triangle_Data {
    double p1[3],p2[3],p3[3];
};

struct Circle_Data {
    double radius;
};

struct Shape {
    virtual double area() const = 0;
    virtual char* getData() = 0;
    virtual ~Shape() {}
};

struct Triangle : public Shape {
    union {
        Triangle_Data tri_data;
        char data[sizeof(Triangle_Data)];
    };
    double area() const { /*...*/ };
    char* getData() { return data; }
    Triangle(char * dat_) {
        std::copy(dat_, dat_+sizeof(Triangle_Data), this->data);
    };
};

struct Circle : public Shape {
    union {
        Circle_Data circ_data;
        char data[sizeof(Circle_Data)];
    };
    double area() const { /*...*/ };
    char* getData() { return data; }
    Circle(char * dat_) {
        std::copy(dat_, dat_+sizeof(Circle_Data), this->data);
    };
};

template<class BaseT>
struct Container {
    int n_objects;
    int sizeof_obj;
    std::vector<char> data;
    Container(...arguments here...) : ...init here... {
        data.resize( sizeof_obj * n_objects );
    }
    void push_back(Shape* obj) {
        // copy the content of obj
        for( int i=0; i<sizeof_obj; ++i)
            data.push_back(*(obj.getData() + i));
    }
    char* operator[] (int idx) {
        return data + idx*sizeof_obj;
    }
};

// usage:
int main() {
    Container<Shape> collection( ..init here.. );
    collection.push_back(new Circle());
    cout << Circle(collection[0]).area() << endl; // horrible, but does it work?
};
```

Of course, this approach has a lot of problems with type safety, alignment, etc.. Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: If you ask for run-time polymorphism, i.e. virtual functions, you can't avoid paying the price of the _`vptr`_ (The _`vtable`_ is unique)

Comment: It would be possible for a language to provide this optimization.  C++ does not.

Comment: "_Base class of course needs to be virtual_" There is no such thing as a "virtual" class. There are only polymorphic classes (and virtual bases, which is a completely different thing). /nitpick

Comment: @curiousguy Thank you for pointing that out. I just fixed it.

Comment: @StoryTeller "_If you ask for run-time polymorphism, i.e. virtual functions, you can't avoid paying the price of the vptr_" Knowing that the dynamic type is the same, you could try to avoid it with dirty tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) it's not necessary to store the same vptr (8 bytes per object?) collection.size() times;

It is not necessary, but objects are independent of one another.

> 2) it's possible to use contiguous storage locations, since their size are known and equal to each other when their type is defined.

... indeed, if you can store concrete instances you can store them in contiguous memory.

---

So, what can you do ?

One solution is to *not* use polymorphic instances, but instead have data and polymorphism separated:

```
struct IShape {
    virtual ~IShape() {}
    virtual double area() const = 0;
};

struct Circle {
    float center, radius;
};

struct IShapeCircle: IShape {
    IShapeCircle(Circle const& c): circle(const_cast<Circle&>(c)) {}
    virtual double area() const { return PI * circle.radius * circle.radius; }

    Circle& circle;
};
```

This way, you only create a polymorphic instance when you need it. And for the storage, we can adapt Massimiliano's solution.

```
struct IShapeVector {
    virtual ~IShapeVector() {}
    std::unique_ptr<IShape> get(size_t i) = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<IShape const> get(size_t i) const = 0;
};

struct IShapeCircleVector: IShapeVector {
    std::unique_ptr<IShape> get(size_t i) {
        return make_unique<IShapeCircle>(_circles.at(i));
    }
    std::unique_ptr<IShape const> get(size_t i) const {
        return make_unique<IShapeCircle const>(_circles.at(i));
    }

    std::vector<Circle> _circles;
};
```

However, you might find that the allocation/deallocation traffic slows you down more than the mere v-ptr.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I will try to implement this and post the result here. In my case, all allocations are made once. The bottleneck is the loops. My problem with `vptr`s is because the size of objects is not much bigger then the size of a pointer, thus saving 8 bytes per object is a big deal.

Comment: @montefuscolo: if this is a tight loop, then you might find the allocation/deallocation (hidden behind `unique_ptr`) to be quite unpleasant. In this case, one solution is to make `IShapeCircle` "resettable" (by using a pointer instead of a reference), allocate one outside the loop (empty) and then have `IShapeVector` take an `IShape&` to be assigned to in `get` instead of returning a new object: `void IShapeVector::assign(IShape& is, size_t i) = 0`. Then, `void IShapeCircleVector::assign(IShape& is, size_t i) { static_cast<IShapeCircle&>(is).reset(_circles.at(i)); }`.

Answer (score 3):

> it's not necessary to store the same vtable (8 bytes per object?) collection.size() times;

You're not storing vtables at all. You're storing pointers which are of same size whether the objects are polymorphic or not. If the collection has `N` objects, then it takes `N * sizeof(void*)` bytes. So the above statement is false.

> it's possible to use contiguous storage locations, since their size are known and equal to each other when their type is defined.

This is not clear. If you're talking about the storage maintained by the container, then yes, the storage maintained by `std::vector` is guaranteed to be contiguous.

Comment: Oops, I mean vptr, not vtable. About std::vector<Base*>, it's guaranteed to be contiguous only to pointer to Base class, not ot objects.

Comment: @montefuscolo: `vptr` or `vtable`, it doesn't matter. You're storing the pointers to the objects, not `vptr`.

Comment: Ok, but each object has a `vtpr`, and this `vtpr` are the same for all objects, since all objects are the same type. Thus, why store this `vtpr` multiple times? is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @montefuscolo: You're NOT storing `vptr` in the vector. Where did you get this idea from?

Comment: I'm not saying that! `vptr` is stored in the object. Suppose my whole program will have only one type of object. Thus, `vptr` is the same for all objects, right? they all have the same members functions ... thus, it's not necessary that each object has a vptr, because they are all the same. That is the point.

Comment: @montefuscolo: Alright. In that case, implement your own mechanism to dispatch dynamically, without relying on the compiler and don't use `virtual` keyword in your class. The mechanism adopted by most compiler uses `vptr`, which is an implementation detail and **therefore is not in your control**. If you have `virtual`, then you will have `vptr` (in most compilers).

Comment: @montefuscolo: (To agree with @Nawaz) If you really are concerned about the `vptr`s in each instance of a polymorphic class, why are you using `virtual`? To circumvent the whole "problem", you can instead use *compile-time polymorphism* and `template`s. Rolling your own mechanism for dynamic dispatch would be a really **big** undertaking!

Comment: @yzt: First, thanks for your patience. I'm in a situation where the type can't be defined at compile time (it must be defined by the end user), but once the type is defined, it never changes.

Answer (score 3):

To address point 2 of your question, if you know that all the objects will be of the **same type**, and you have this information at run-time, you may think of virtualizing the container and create it with a factory. Just to give a sketch of the idea:

```
class ShapeContainer {
 /* Virtual base */
}; 

class CircleContainer : public ShapeContainer {
/* ... */
private:
    std::vector<Circle> impl_;
}

class ShapeContainerFactory {
 /* Factory for ShapeContainer derived objects */
};

int main() {
    ShapeContainer& collection = ShapeContainerFactory.create("Circle");
    collection.push_back( Circle() );
};
```

In this case you will be guaranteed to store contiguously not the pointers or references to the polymorphic objects, but the objects themselves.

Comment: That doesn't solve much, really. *Each object* will still have a vptr embedded in it...

Comment: @StoryTeller That's the meaning of the premise "To address point 2 of your question..."

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes but the vptr is just a pointer, unless your objects are very light it will not make a huge difference.